# How to do an on duplicate key update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this SQL statement for inserting data into my database, I just need to update instead when a duplicate value is entered, how can I do this do I need to use the primary key or can I use a specific value

The auto_incremented column that you see is the primary key called license_id

SQL CODE

```
INSERT INTO License
  (license_id, 
  license_number, 
  start_date, 
  end_date, 
  duration, 
  expiry_date)
VALUES
  ('5', 
  '00005555', 
  '2015-11-22', 
  '2015-11-23', 
  '1', 
  '2015-11-24')

on duplicate key update  ????
```

What do I fill in by the question marks

I just done something like this, it didnt work

```
INSERT INTO License
  (license_id, 
  license_number, 
  start_date, 
  end_date, 
  duration, 
  expiry_date)
VALUES
  ('5', 
  '00005555', 
  '2015-11-23', 
  '2015-11-24', 
  '1', 
  '2015-11-25')

on duplicate key update license_id = values(license_id)
```

Comment: Can you describe what scenario you have where you might be getting a duplicate index or unique column updated and how you would like to handle it?  Please read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: I have a fieldset with form in Sencha Architect, the person needs to enter a value into the form, I need to be able to insert if the record does not exist and update if the record exists

Comment: So if a duplicate insert comes in, do you want to update the value of the `license_id` ?

Comment: I am not clear, you mentioned that license_id an is auto-incremented field. So how can it be duplication? And if it is auto-incremented so why the user can edit it?

Comment: You should not be doing this on an auto increment column.  Rather, you need to rethink your logic.

Comment: so let me explain, a user must be able to edit existing records in the database, my database is huge it links licenses  and other tables together with primary and foreign keys, the person should see data in a form when they open up a view for a specific license like license_number = 5000, that would have other data attached to it, so when they open this view they would add data to it or update existing data, I just needed a way of updating and inserting in one statement instead of having seperate forms for update and insert, so thats why they must edit primary key fields that are A_I

Comment: Can I do it on the license_number column

Comment: in the form they are not going to actually edit the primary key

Comment: the data just needs to be collected by the form and used for updating existing record, they will never be able to actually change the primary key

Comment: you should do a select before your insert and check if there is a duplicate, if so then execute an update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in doing `on duplicate key update license_id = values(license_id)` because the `license_id` you're trying to insert already exists in the table and it would just change the `license_id` of an existing record to the same value as before. Rather, the `on duplicate key update` is intended to update the other values. In your case it could maybe be, for example,

```
on duplicate key update
    license_number = values(license_number)
    start_date = values(start_date),
    end_date = values(end_date),
    duration = values(duration),
    expiry_date = values(expiry_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it, i tried without the primary key and the database just got confused, it entered a new record so I did this, used a different table

```
INSERT INTO Product (product_id,product_name, version) VALUES ('1', 'nfinityX', '5')
on duplicate key update product_id='1', product_name='infinity', version='5';
```

There is alot of related code that you have not seen, which makes it hard for you guys to understand the context of what I mean, but this seams to have worked, as you can see above.

I had that record already, and tested what I wrote above and it worked, I had to put primary key so it knows what row to update, otherwise it will update other rows and get confused. Is this the right way, I dont know.